# Angular 8 - File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation

Tags: angular, api, angular8

I built an Angular component to get messages from an API and display it to the user. Once all the messages are displayed in the UI from the service subscription, a file upload option is made visible where the user can also upload their own messages using Excel sheet.

Everything works fine up to displaying 150 messages in the UI. After i get 150+ messages from the API and display it in the UI, the file upload option appears as expected, but when the option is clicked, the file picker dialog box is not appearing, rather it shows this warning in the console:

> File chooser dialog can only be shown with a user activation

The file upload option is a normal input element:

```
<input type="file" />
```

Why's that? Is it because of the 150+ messages that slows down the component? How can i overcome this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in stackblitz?

Comment: You dont need to provide the exact data. Just an array with dummy data and the input implementation is enough.